# Eclipse Organize Import converts Joda time to java.time for Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, jodatime, java-time

When I run a full organize import converts the following imports:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
```

to:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
```

I tried to make sense out of it and see if I could disable, tough luck. I find this really aggressive and annoying. Any solutions?

Comment: This usually happens when there's only one option available (only one class with that name in the classpath) - if there are more than one, it usually shows a window where you can choose the package. So, a silly question: have you checked if joda classes are in the classpath of your project?

Comment: I tried again and and now it works looks like project wasn't imported properly (bug MDEP-98) had to build it one time command line first. Thanks for the help.